# Does RNGD accept other entropy input with Debian11, kernel Debian-5.10.0-17?

Tags: random-number-generator, debian-buster

Aug 06, 2022

I upgraded to the Debian-5.10.0-17-amd64 kernel recently and was not impressed.  I regressed back to the Debian-5.10.0-9-amd64 kernel.

Under the '9' kernel, I run a script that cat's entropy_available to a log file, sleeps 15 seconds and repeats 480 times at 2:00 am.  The script runs for about 2 hours.
The first test was with the kernel only running.  It was alive and moving in the pool.
The second test was with the kernel and rngd running.  It was alive and slightly more aggressive in the pool.
The third test was with rngd stopped and randomsound and the kernel running.  The entropy pool was quick, fast and filled up to set parameters.

I am fairly sure that the random number generator is working.

Here is a copy of the script, from which the log file contents are copy and pasted into a spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet is then used to generate the line chart.

[image: random chart results]

Now with the upgrade to '17' in place, the graph is very simple to draw

```
300
256  _________________________________________________________________


128
```

0

I get no feed back from the system.  Is the random number generator running or is it stuck?  Is it accepting rngd or randomsound input?

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the script, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

Current Linux kernels [no longer have an "entropy pool".](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/) They use a completely different PRNG, which remains secure without entropy accounting (and which is now [the same](https://lwn.net/Articles/884875/) for all 'random' devices).

The RNG still needs to collect data for initial seeding every boot, but once done /dev/random never runs out, so `rngd` and `haveged` are more or less obsolete for that purpose. (The kernel also has a built-in "jitter entropy gathering" function which mostly does what `haveged` did, making it obsolete for early entropy gathering as well.)

- [Replacing /dev/urandom](https://lwn.net/Articles/686033/) (2016)
- [random: replace urandom pool with a CRNG](https://lwn.net/Articles/691071/) (2016)
- [Removing the Linux /dev/random blocking pool](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/) (2020)
- [Uniting the Linux random-number devices](https://lwn.net/Articles/884875/) (2022)
- [kernel 5.10.119 caused the values of /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail and poolsize to be 256](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704737/kernel-5-10-119-caused-the-values-of-proc-sys-kernel-random-entropy-avail-and-p)